# Android: call a custom dialog from acceleration sensor

Tags: android

I am new to android and now I am learning sensor. I do a small program just like:

```
@Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER){
            float[] values = event.values;
            float x = values[0];
            float y = values[1];
            float z = values[2];
            float SR_Accelation = (x * x + y * y + z * z) / (SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH * SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH);
            long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            if(SR_Accelation >= 2){
                if(currentTime - lastUpdateTime < 200){
                    return;
                }
                lastUpdateTime = currentTime;
                Toast.makeText(ImgTest0130Activity.this, "Shake it!!!", 0).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

It works well and will pop up the toast. Now I want to pop up a dialog instead of toast. I know how to create a dialog, but how can I put it into program? How to call it?

Answer (score 0):

First, the developer site has a pretty good explanation of dialogs here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html.

Most kinds of dialogs are launched with a call to .show(), see [the docs here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#show%28%29). You'll create your dialog, and then do something like yourDialog.show() wherever you had been starting the Toast.

The android docs are really good for explaining these sorts of things, I'd advise starting in [the Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html) and looking at the documentation for any kind of object you want to use.